# Transforming variables using ‘foreach’

Tags: stata

I have a set of variables. I want to transform each variable in this set (‘y’) as follows: y' = (y-min(y))(max(y)-min(y)). That is, for each observation of each variable, I want to subtract the minimum value of that variable, and then divide the result by the difference between the maximum and minimum values of that variable.

I want to implement this via a loop, using `foreach`, but coding it as above (using the `min()` and `max()` functions) produces an error message. Are there any alternatives? Or must this just be done manually?

Comment: I'd delete the equivalent question on Cross Validated and then the reputation loss from a downvote will be restored. It no longer serves any purpose at all.

Comment: If one of the responses below has addressed your question, please recognize their contribution by selecting their response as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to adapt the example below. The command `summarize` stores the values you need in your formula in the returned `r()` values.

```
sysuse auto

local vars price mpg weight length 

foreach var of local vars {
    summarize `var'
    replace `var' = (`var' - r(min)) / (r(max) - r(min))
}
```

Comment: See my answer. equivalent in spirit. There is a smidgen of efficiency in insisting on `meanonly` and a smidgen of precision loss in asking for the local macro persona of (e.g.) `r(min)`.  `r(min)` is stored to maximum precision but using single quotes first yields a string representation. which Stata then has to translate into a numeric representation to do the calculation. Hence use `r(min)` and `r(max)` directly in problems like these.

Comment: I agree regarding the scalars that is a good point, and I have updated the answer. However, adding something like an extra option that might not be known to everyone, can cause the code to be confusing to some, and given what little difference in efficiency it actually makes, I think that the better solution, given all aspects, is without `meanonly`

Comment: Thank you for pointing to this option, @NickCox. It's indeed very useful. The helpfile says that this option only calculates the mean, though. Looking at the list of return one can see that this is not true, but the helpfile is misleading and makes this a very obscure option.

Comment: @Luiza Andrade  Indeed. I wrote an article on this very point in the _Stata Journal_ which you should able to find with a -search summarize, sj- (omit the dashes).

Comment: @TheIceBear Well, SO is supposed to cater for professionals and enthusiast programmers. Beginners may get more than they expect.

Comment: @NickCox agreed. And therefore I do not think it is bad that you suggested it, I just think that not including `meanonly` makes the code the most usable to the most people in the Stata community which I assign great value to.

Comment: Indeed. The two answers should stand and I upvoted yours.

Comment: https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0135 is a link to the article mentioned in a previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

There is no data example in the question, nor any indication of your variable names. This is an example you can run.

```
sysuse auto, clear

ds, has(type numeric)

foreach v in `r(varlist)' {
    su `v', meanonly
    gen `v'_scaled = (`v' - r(min)) / (r(max) - r(min))
}

su *scaled

    Variable |        Obs        Mean    Std. Dev.       Min        Max
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
price_scaled |         74    .2278444    .2338086          0          1
  mpg_scaled |         74    .3205965    .1995001          0          1
rep78_scaled |         69    .6014493    .2474831          0          1
headroom_s~d |         74    .4266409    .2417128          0          1
trunk_scaled |         74    .4864865    .2376336          0          1
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
weight_sca~d |         74    .4089154    .2523356          0          1
length_sca~d |         74     .504752    .2446851          0          1
 turn_scaled |         74    .4324324    .2199677          0          1
displaceme~d |         74    .3418997    .2654255          0          1
gear_ratio~d |         74    .4852146    .2684042          0          1
-------------+---------------------------------------------------------
foreign_sc~d |         74    .2972973    .4601885          0          1
```

The functions `min()` and `max()` in Stata require two or more arguments and operate rowwise in any case. They don't yield the minimum and maximum of a variable. You could use `egen` but the direct route of a loop and calling up `summarize` is preferable. Note that despite its name the `meanonly` option does produce the minimum and maximum.